# Javascript array name is not being defined

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm following a Javascript tutorial on youtube. However, I am getting an error that I don't understand. The array definition seems ok to me.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: words is not defined

```
window.addEventListener("load",initial());
//Global variables
let time = 5;
let score =0;
let isPlaying;

//DOM variables
const wordInput_input= document.querySelector('#word-input');
const currentWord_h2 = document.querySelector('#current-word');
const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('#time');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const seconds = document.querySelector('#seconds');

const words = ['hat', 'river', 'lucky', 'state'];

//Initialise game
function initial(){
    //Load word from the array
    showWord(words);

}

//Pick and show random word
function showWord(words){
    //Generate random array index
    const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
    // Output random word
    currentWord_h2.innerHTML = words[randIndex];
}
```

Comment: You are supposed to use `window.addEventListener('load', initial);`. This will call initial for you once the window loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are adding `initial` as an event listener on the first line (`window.addEventListener("load",initial());`) `words` is not yet defined.

Try moving the event listener to the bottom

The above has to do with Hoisting in Javascript. `const` declared variables are **not hoisted**. You can read more about [hoisting here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You're calling the `initial` function instead of attaching it as an event listener. Change `window.addEventListener("load",initial());` to `window.addEventListener("load",initial);`. So, you're calling the `showWords` function with `words`, even before it is initialized.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", initial);
//Global variables
let time = 5;
let score = 0;
let isPlaying;

//DOM variables
const currentWord_h2 = document.querySelector('#current-word');

const words = ['hat', 'river', 'lucky', 'state'];

//Initialise game
function initial() {
  //Load word from the array
  showWord(words);

}

//Pick and show random word
function showWord(words) {
  //Generate random array index
  const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
  // Output random word
  currentWord_h2.innerHTML = words[randIndex];
}
```

```html
<h2 id="current-word">Test</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you defined the variable 'words' as a global constant, you can call it from any function, the only thing that is happening to you and shows you undefine, the script is running so fast that at the same time that it is being created, you are also trying use within the function, simply place a small delay in the function so you expect it to be created to be used, I'll put an example of 100 milliseconds, is easy to implement and improve.
I hope it has been helpful for you.
have a happy day.

```js
window.addEventListener("load",initial());
//Global variables
let time = 5;
let score =0;
let isPlaying;

//DOM variables
const wordInput_input= document.querySelector('#word-input');
const currentWord_h2 = document.querySelector('#current-word');
const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('#time');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const seconds = document.querySelector('#seconds');

const words = ['hat', 'river', 'lucky', 'state'];

//Initialise game
function initial(){
    //Load word from the array
      showWord();
}

//Pick and show random word
function showWord(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    //Test Call to words Now is Completed
    console.log(words);
     //Generate random array index
     const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
     // Output random word
     currentWord_h2.innerHTML = words[randIndex];
    },100);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="word" id="word-input">
<input type="text" value="current" id="current-word">
<input type="text" value="20" id="score">
<input type="text" value="05:00" id="time">

</body>
</html>
```